# Chrome autocomplete thinks my "firstName" field is a credit card

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete

Google Chrome thinks my input

```html
<input
  name="firstName"
  id="firstName" type="text"
  placeholder="John" font-size="16"
  class="sc-fznKkj XyZMK"
>
```

is a credit card, as shown in the autocomplete field inspector and by the fact that a saved Credit Card is offered. It does that on the `lastName` field too, and another number type field somewhere in another form.

What I do not get is that it worked just as expected in our dev environment, and goes wrong only in staging (both are pretty much the same deployment process, same s3 + cloudfront hosting, same code of the same build).

Any clues?

It gets weirder: changing the `name` field to `first-name` instead of `firstName` fixes it. I don't need to change both input names, only the first one does it. But surely I should be able to name my field however I please?

Comment: Chrome also uses the <label> text when detecting cc-number fields. The detection is language specific. We had a English client showing this problem, but changing the clients OS language to Swedish fixed it. Note that the page had no localization support and always was rendered in Swedish.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In HTML forms, the `autocomplete` attribute is used to tell browsers what type of data should go into a particular input.

(More info at [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete).)

For a first name, for example, you should use `autocomplete="given-name"`, and for a last name, use `autocomplete="family-name"`.

Adding these attributes to the inputs which are being recognised incorrectly should solve your problem.

---

As to why some inputs don't have an `autocomplete` attribute yet are still recognised correctly: when no `autocomplete` attribute is found, the browser tries to decide 'intelligently' what should be put into this field.

To do this, the `name` attribute is most commonly used. If it is `username` or `password` for example, the browser will probably recognise these words as they are very common input descriptions. If it is `myinput6`, then the browser won't be able to recognise anything.

In your case, it seems that the browser recognised `name="first-name"`, but had trouble recognising the slightly different `name="firstName"`. However, as you said, you should be able to give your `name` attributes any value you want, and to do this, you should use the `autocomplete` attribute.